# using Yahoo Messenger to send SMS

Tags: yahoo, firefox, yahoo-mail, sms, linux

When using Yahoo Messenger to send SMS, I get:

> Sorry, but Yahoo! Messenger is currently unavailable. Please try again
>   later.

I receive this error message after [step three](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SLN431&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1354831458009&locale=en_US&y=PROD_MAIL_ML) below:

```
To send SMS text messages in Yahoo! Mail:

    Sign in to Yahoo! Mail.
    Select the down arrow next to "Compose Message."
    Select SMS.
```

I see that this question is [asked](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110612131438AAjT0xI) and not answered on yahoo.

Perhaps a credit card or other authorization is required to send?  Or OS problem?  Apparently a phone is required to **receive** SMS, which is fine.  I just want to **send** SMS messages and would be willing to pay the going rate (skype is about fifteen cents, IIRC).

> In order to receive SMS messages, your friend must have an SMS/text
>   messaging-enabled mobile phone. Standard text/data rates apply.

I know that skype requires authentication, but if that's part of the directions, pardon, I don't see that.  RTFM answers appreciated, please just quote or point to the part I'm missing.